# How to enable BHO in Edge IE compatibility mode? Microsoft says it supports BHO in MS Edge's IE compatibility Mode but it seems to be not working

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, bho

I have my existing BHO (Browser Helper Object) created for IE / Internet Explorer. Since Internet Explorer is completely removed/discontinued from Windows 11 as MS Edge browser allows to run legacy Web Apps in IE compatible mode. As we have customer's legacy web apps which still requires IE 11 and BHO (Browser Helper Object) for some of the business functionalities to work. We are able to run legacy web apps in Edge IE compatible mode but BHO (Browser Helper Object) is not working. Microsoft Edge's official [online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#ie-mode-supports-the-following-internet-explorer-functionality) link says BHO (Browser Helper Object) is supported in MS Edge IE Compatible Mode. I tried registering BHO as we used to do with Internet Explorer but it doesn't get triggered when I open Web App in Edge IE compatible mode. Herewith sharing link to BHO [code](https://github.com/reicolina/ie-bho-extension) and registration process which I referred.
Requesting help or pointers if any to make BHO (Browser Helper Object) to work with MS Edge IE Compatible mode.

1. Enabled IE Compatible mode in MS Edge referring [link](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=118968).
2. Tried creating BHO using [code](https://github.com/reicolina/ie-bho-extension) and followed registration steps.
3. Microsoft Edge's official [online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#ie-mode-supports-the-following-internet-explorer-functionality) link says BHO (Browser Helper Object) is supported in MS Edge IE Compatible Mode.

Comment: Actually, I didn't see the alert in neither IE11 app nor in Edge IE mode using the BHO code you provide. I can only see the BHO is enabled in both IE11 app and Edge IE mode. Yes, IE mode should support BHOs, if you encounter any compatibility issue in Edge IE mode in your app, you can connect with the App Assure team for remediation assistance. You can submit a [request for assistance](https://fasttrack.microsoft.com/dl/daa) through their website or reach out via email (ACHELP@microsoft.com).

Comment: Yu Zhou, You will not see alert with the BHO code I shared here since its not working in case of Windows 11. But you will surely see it in Windows 10 as it still not completely removed Internet Explorer and using internet explorer you can see alert for IE 11 web apps.  Will reach out to app assure team but let me be clear here its not related to my App but its about Edge IE compatibility mode not properly support BHO even if it claims.

Comment: I test with Windows 10 and I don't see alert in IE 11. The BHO is installed successfully: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g8jg.png. The behaviors are the same in IE and Edge IE mode.

Comment: @YuZhou, Can you change below line of code in BHO.cs file-  
change from- RegistryKey ourKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid); 
change to- RegistryKey ourKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid, true);
Then re-register (unregister previous and register again using regasm) this BHO.
To register in 32 bit and 64 bit modes use below command- 
1. "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" ieextension.dll /codebase
2. "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" ieextension.dll /codebase
Close MS Edge and IE related processes from task manager before verification.

Comment: I test according to your steps and now I can see the alert in IE 11. I can also see the alert in Edge IE mode. For example, if I open Edge and load a site in IE mode: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuPHx.gif. So Microsoft is right, BHO is supported in Edge IE mode.

Comment: @Yu Zhou, My point is, its not possible to enable BHO in Windows 11 as it has completely removed Internet Explorer which is not the case with Windows 10 where you also seen it is possible to make BHO working by use of Internet Explorer Add On configuration. Also, you may be aware MS is going to remove Internet Explorer from WIndows 10 in few months as part of their patch release. In such case, Is there any way to enable BHO in MS Edge for IE Compatible mode?

Answer (score 0):

First, "its not possible to enable BHO in Windows 11 as it has completely removed Internet Explorer" is wrong. The **Internet Explorer 11 desktop application** is not available on Windows 11. The MSHTML engine still exists as part of the Windows 11 operating system to power IE mode. On Windows 10, it's also the same. It's just **Internet Explorer 11 desktop application** is removed, not completely remove IE engine. For more information about IE 11 retirement, you can refer to [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549).

Second, on Windows 11, you can still enable BHO using the same way as on Windows 10. You can manage IE add-ons by search **Internet Options-> Programs-> Manage add-ons**.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is not straight forward to use these settings which are spread across different places (registry, group policy, internet options, etc.) and no proper documentation from Microsoft on Edge IE compatibility and when it comes to scale of hundreds or thousands of systems (agent Desktops/VDIs) it further complicates to apply these settings on every system.

Comment: All the documents for Edge IE mode are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode). If you want to apply settings on many systems, I think you can use group policy. For the manage add-ons setting, you can use [this policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/enable-and-disable-add-ons-using-administrative-templates-and-group-policy#using-the-local-group-policy-editor-to-manage-group-policy-objects).